# Non-standard filesystem for Windows 10 USB flash memory?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, replication

I am using a `32gb USB flash memory` to replicate files between several `Windows 10` PCs. In times of cloud and high-speed networks, this might be old fashioned, but it keeps my data private and is rather easy so far.

The replication is based on [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). At the end of a work session, I run a script to incrementally copy changes from SSD to flash memory. To continue my work on another PC, I run the same script to copy the changes from flash memory to SSD.

One problem remains to be solved:
How do I prevent data loss, in case my USB flash memory gets stolen?

I have done some experiments with encryption solutions like [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) and [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/). In terms of copy speed and user convenience, such solutions are not attractive to me. The same applies to encrypting USB flash drives like [iStorage datAshur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VG8CYTX).

My last experiment for the time being was to install a non-standard filesystem driver which should be a hurdle for an occasional finder of my flash memory.  I tried [WinBtrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs), an open source implementation of the [btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) filesystem. But again, copy speed was slow and I got a blue screen when I removed by USB stick.

**My question:**

> Is there any non-standard filesystem or other method known to keep a flash memory halfway unreadable for most people and still useful for multi-gigabyte replication?

Comment: Did you really experience speed problems with BitLocker & co? Modern PCs are fast enough to encrypt/decrypt multiple gigabytes of data per second, which is way faster than your USB flash drive.

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, and it seems that [I am not the only one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/67697/slow-writing-on-usb-3-key-encrypted-with-bitlocker.html). But I take your point to try this route again.

Comment: Hm okay I hadn’t considered a problem specific to USB flash drives. Because with my work laptop’s fully encrypted SSD, there are no performance problems.